# How to only add in database the textbox that has value

Tags: c#

This is my code when adding value in my database but my problem is the `,` is showing and I only want to add the value of the textbox that has value

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = MAAAYYK; Initial Catalog = dbFoodReservation; Integrated Security = True");

SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand();
cm = new SqlCommand("Insert into tbl_Reservation(Food)Values(@Food)", con);
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Food", txtboxfood1.Text + "," + txtboxfood2.Text + "," + txtboxfood3.Text + "," + txtboxfood4.Text);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of ways of doing this, you can try [`string.Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join):

```
var foodValues = new List<string>()
{
    txtboxfood1.Text, txtboxfood2.Text, txtboxfood3.Text , txtboxfood4.Text
}

var foodText = string.Join(",", foodValues.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)));

...
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Food", foodText);
```